# How can I replicate this swirly smoke effect with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I found this somewhere and would like to replicate it with geometry nodes:

[image]

I'm getting close, but it looks like crap, still :(

[image]

My nodes:

[image]

Comment: Tip: The size of the circles remains unchanged, but is small at the beginning, large in the middle ...and small again at the end. Optical illusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing here is actually a whole bunch of optical tricks and it all depends a lot on perspective.

You can basically only approach the result you're looking for through trial and error.

However, here I have a relatively usable basis for you.

[image]

The following aspects were considered here:

- First the line is animated, on which you then instantiate the circles.
- The thereby detectable rotation of the individual points can then additionally be transferred to the instances, which strengthens the effect.
- The instantiated circles are then randomly rotated and scaled to add some variability.
- The points are increasingly (variably) staggered towards the back, which can add to the effect.

Here is the node group at a glance:

[image]

And here is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Although, now the big circles lead the movement, in the ref smaller ones did. To make this perfect, I noticed you can just change the 'Animate the points'-frame's green node's 4.580 to -4.580 and the smaller circles lead the way :) Nice job, very elegant nodes!

Answer (score 3):

Got a little closer, still quite far away

[image]

And the nodes are not the cleanest:

[image]